# i can not download my pdf files on server

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

while i am trying to generate reports to pdf,exel.

if i wanna download to excel its working in each function.
while i am trying to download  the reports into pdf,in some function its working but in some function its given me this error

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /sc/reports/home/print_admin_report on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

any help approciated

note :thier is no problems in local server,only problems is with online server

thankx in advance

Comment: did u give permission to ur apache/www-data to read the folder?

Comment: yes on same folder and some controller another function is working,

Answer (score 0):

this works for me on both local and server, give a try

```
function download()
{   
    $base_location = 'files/';
    $FILENAME_VAR = 'YOURFILENAME.pdf';
    if ($FILENAME_VAR)
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$FILENAME_VAR);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($base_location . $FILENAME_VAR));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($base_location . $FILENAME_VAR);
    }
}
```

Replace $base_location and the YOURFILENAME.pdf with yours and then create link to this method in ur page